# Angular unit tests for module run method

Tags: angularjs

In our project, we use requirejs with angularjs. We have a main application module (app) and module for all services (app-services), module for all controllers (app-controllers), module for all filters (app-filters). Modules app-controllers, app-services etc.. are added as dependencies to main app module.

main application module

```
var mainAppModule = angular.module('app', [
        'ngResource',
        'ngSanitize',
        'app.controllers',
        'app.directives',
        'app.services',
        'app.filters',
        'app.routes'
    ]);

mainAppModule.run(['$location', '$rootScope', function ($location, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.sayHello = function(name) {
        console.log("Hello" + name);
    }
}]);
```

How can write the Karma/Jasmine tests for mainAppModule.run method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, logic should remain outside run method (e.g. included in controllers, services, directives, filters, etc.). You can, however, test your run method as follows. Using jasmine syntax:

```
//Updating this method to use $log for DI
mainAppModule.run(['$location', '$rootScope', '$log', function ($location, $rootScope, $log) {
    $rootScope.sayHello = function(name) {
        $log.info("Hello" + name);
    }
}]);
//---------------------------

//Jasmine test
describe("app run", function () {
    var $rootScope;
    var $log;

    beforeEach(module("app"));
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$log_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $log = _$log_;
    }));

    it("should expose sayHello function to $rootScope", function () {
        expect(angular.isFunction($rootScope.sayHello)).toBe(true);
    });

    describe("sayHello function", function () {
        it("should log 'Hello name'", function () {
            spyOn($log, "info");
            $rootScope.sayHello("test");

            expect($log.info).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Hello test");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This approach worked for me. Accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best way is simply to use state-based verification that the "run" method executed. In the case of the specific example you provided, inject $rootScope into a test and verify that it has a property named "sayHello" of type function.

IIRC your application run methods should be called automatically by Jasmine when you call the [angular.mock.module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module) function from your test.